# Dropbox get public link metadata

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to access a public shared Dropbox file metadata in my app. I need file name, mime type and creation date.

With v1 API I used the /1/metadata/link with application authentication. I used only my app key and app secret in the request (and of course the shared URL).

According to Dropbox documentation in v2 I should use the /get_shared_link_metadata

However the /get_shared_link_metadata call requires user authentication. What if the user doesn't have a dropbox account or don't want to attach it to my app?

Is there any way to get information about the public file without forcing the user to login to dropbox?

Comment: That's the right endpoint, but it unfortunately doesn't support app-auth, only user-auth. I'll pass this along as a feature request for app-auth support.

Comment: @Greg: Thanks, I hope it will be accepted.